# How to match items in two different lists and create a new list based on the matches in python?

Tags: python

I have a list in python called "multiple_ids" with a bunch of ids and I have another list called "ids_singular" as well as another list called "alias".

"ids_singular" and "alias" are both the same size and the index of "ids_singular" corresponds to the index of "alias". What this means is that  say the third value in the  "alias"  list is another way to represent the third  value in "ids_singular" .

The list "miltiple_ids"  is larger than the other two lists and includes all values in "ids_singular', but there are duplicates as well. Every id in "mutiple_ids" can be found in "ids_singular".

What I am looking to do is for code that will replace each item (id) in "multiple_ids" with the matching alias from the "alias" list based on the "ids_singular" list.

I have tried a double for loop where I first iterate through all the "multiple_ids", then iterate through all the "ids_singular" and if they are a match , create a new list that has the alias for the id based on the same index of "alias" list.

```
for i in (multiple_ids):
    for j in range(len(ids_singular)):
        if i==ids_singular[j]:
            new_multiple_ids.append(alias[j])
print(new_multiple_ids)
```

When I run this code, nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

```
multiple_ids = ['abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'def', 'xyz']
ids_singular = ['abc','def','xyz']
alias = ['a_abc','a_def', 'a_xyz']

d = dict(zip(ids_singular, alias))
result = [d[item] for item in multiple_ids]

print(result)  $ -> ['a_abc', 'a_def', 'a_xyz', 'a_def', 'a_xyz']
```